# On a possibility of hiding AllJoyn interface

Tags: alljoyn

Is it possible to hide an AllJoyn interface ? I.e. not expose via introspection, about etc., but invoke when a specific call is made.

Thanks !

Comment: This is very vague and it is hard to give any input to you question. Please edit it and describe you problem more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bus object that doesn't support the org.allseen.Introspectable or org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable interfaces.

This is difficult to do, however, because you would basically need to change the implementation of `ajn::BusAttachment::Internal` so that it doesn't automatically add these interfaces (i.e., the calls to `org::freedesktop::DBus::CreateInterfaces()` and `org::alljoyn::CreateInterfaces()` located in `BusAttachment.cc`). This would mean building your own version of AllJoyn Core based on this modified implementation. **NOTE:** Doing this would mean your product is not using a compliant base implementation of AllJoyn Core and would therefore likely not pass AllJoyn Certification.